# Magento Product Image Moved to the righte

Tags: magento

Can someone help me in figuring out why all of the sudden the image file for my product moved to the right and disrupted the layout.  I have been through many of the files and i cannot figure out what happened.  Very confused

http://www.shadecontrol.com/index.php/view-by-shape/quick-order-classic/jmc0908as48.html

Answer (score 0):

Your current html/css is

```
<div class="product-shop">...</div>
<div class="product-img-box">...</div>


 .col1-layout .product-view .product-shop {
    float: left;
    width: 360px;
 }


 .product-view .product-img-box {
    float: left;
    width: 256px;
 }
```

Because both div are floating left you will have the product detail before the product image.

You could either change the css to

```
 .col1-layout .product-view .product-shop {
    float: right;
    width: 360px;
 }
```

or change the order of the divs within  /app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<div class="product-img-box">...</div>
<div class="product-shop">...</div>
```